# How to display text the user inputs as a different character in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tty

I'm trying to make a username and password program in Python, and although it isn't necessary to the final program, I thought it would be nice to make it display a different character when they input their text. Like most password fields, which may display something like an asterisk (*). So I was wondering how I might go about displaying their input as a different character. Thank you for any help :)

Comment: use the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) module

Comment: You should read the password from the tty (so that you can disable echoing of characters) and write your `*` on standard output or on the tty

Comment: @Paulo Scardine I'm trying to make my program check against a username and password as a fun project, that would defeat the point of what I'm doing :P

Comment: Actually what I wrote may be wrong: while echoing is disabled, characters written won't be shown. I don't think there exists a safe way

Answer (score 2):

Using the `getch` recipe from the question " [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) "

```
def getpass(prompt):
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    password = ''
    while True:
        c = getch()
        if c == '\r':
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            return password
        password += c
        sys.stdout.write('*')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Proof:

```
>>> getpass('secret: ')
secret: ********
'asdfsafd'
```

Echoing `*` for each character typed may fell cool from the UI perspective but will compromise security a bit because it gives up the length of the password. I guess that is why the builtin `getpass` module will not echo anything.

[update]

According to [Andrea Corbellini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913824/andrea-corbellini), this implementation will leak keystrokes if the system is under heavy load, because it is resetting the tty before returning - characters may be echoed after getch() has returned and before getch() is called again. Looks like this is very hard to accomplish in a safe way, so probably this is the reason why the builtin `getpass` is not providing a visual feedback for each keystroke.

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but on UNIX this solution is subject to race conditions: if you type a character while `if c == '\r' ... password += c ; sys.stdout.write('*') ...` is executed, then the character will be displayed

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Are you sure? We are not using asynchronous I/O here, `getch` is blocking. If you are able to trigger this bug, could you be kind enough to post a reproducible case?

Comment: The problem is not when `getch` is running, but when it's not running. Try putting a `for i in range(100000): pass` after the call to `getch()` (to simulate slow code or high CPU load) and run your script holding `a` pressed. You'll see an alternance of `*` and `a` characters on the terminal

Comment: The `getch()` implementation you are using is resetting the tty before returning. So characters may be echoed after `getch()` has returned and before `getch()` is called again

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is hard enough to trigger that the OP can use it in practice if he accepts the risk of echoing some keystrokes when the system is under heavy load.